# What would be the objective functions for this problem?

Tags: optimization, operations-research

I have the following data (this is just a sample of my entire dataset):

```
# Distance PriceIndex Rating
1 400      3          5
2 420      2          4
3 500      1          2
```

Considering the PriceIndex indicates if a venue is less (1) or more (4) pricey, and the rating from 1 (worst) to 5 (best).

There is not preference between Distance, PriceIndex and Rating, so how should my objective function should be so I can provide the number of the best solutions considering the following objectives?

- minimize Distance
- minimize PriceIndex
- maximize Rating

UPDATE

The only restrictions this problem has are: Rating must be > 2 and another binary var (let's call it X) that must be equal to 1.

This will be used in a mobile application developed for a college homework. So think about apps like Foursquare (now Swarm) that suggest restaurants nearby. The idea here is to provide not just the places nearby but also the best rated and less pricey.

This homework is about solving multiobjective optimization problems using heuristics and/or metaheuristics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edited based on OP comments**

You can use the concept of "non-dominated" solutions to great effect here. Since you've stated that there is no preference for any of the criteria, we can't really use a preemptive approach. Also, you are not really looking for *the* optimal site, so an objective function doesn't really make sense here.

First, lets calculate a normalized distance on a 1-5 scale: 1=Distance to furthest site, 5=distance to closest site, others are calculated as:

$$\mathrm{DistFactor_i=} 5-\frac{dist_i-dist_{min}}{dist_{max}-dist_{min}}$$

Next, invert your cost factor so that 1=Most expensive, 5=least expensive. This will allow us to represent each site in the space $(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{[1,5]}^3$.

You can now use one of the algorithms in [this paper](http://www.ijcaonline.org/journal/number25/pxc387764.pdf) or [here](http://www.isca.in/rjrs/archive/special_issue2012/3.ISCA-ISC-2012-5CITS-17.pdf) to find the "nondominated" set of points in this space. It is the sites corresponding to these points that your app should return.

Comment: Suppose that I choose the goal programming, what algorithm should I use to solve it faster? Does using a genetic algorithm make any sense for this kind of problem?

Comment: @JulianoNunesSilvaOliveira depends on what constraints you have. How many sites can you select?

Comment: It can select one or more sites.

Comment: @JulianoNunesSilvaOliveira ok..then please revise your post to give a complete description of the problem. What are the constraints you are working under? Right now, what is stopping me from simply chooseing ALL the sites (and hence getting all possible optimal answers)

Comment: thank you for taking your time to help me. I just added some more info on this question. Hope it helps you understand what I need. I'm really new to this and this is the final assignment in my college course.

Comment: @JulianoNunesSilvaOliveira From your description, you don't need any objective function. If it can suggest any sites that meet that definition, then your app is just displaying information subject to search criteria (e.g. like Zillow). For an objective function to make sense, you need to be trying to balance several critreia. Also, an objective function will result in ONE site selected as "optimal".

Comment: @JulianoNunesSilvaOliveira See my edited answer. I think having your app produce non-dominated solutions is the way to go.

Comment: just to clarify one thing. When I said that one or more places could be returned, that was because I've read that in a multi objective problem there isn't an optimal solution. What we can find are best possible solutions.

Comment: @JulianoNunesSilvaOliveira yep, that would be "non dominated solutions", just use one of the algorithms I linked to.